# Why doesn't my container app job scale up when there are messages on the queue?

Tags: azure-storage-queues, azure-container-apps, keda

I have a container app job in Azure, and an Azure Storage Queue. The container app job should scale up when there are messages on the queue, and scale down to zero when the queue is empty. Here is the configuration for the job:

```
"eventTriggerConfig": {
    "parallelism": 1,
    "replicaCompletionCount": 1,
    "scale": {
      "maxExecutions": 10,
      "minExecutions": 0,
      "pollingInterval": 30,
      "rules": [
        {
          "auth": [
            {
              "secretRef": "connection-string-secret",
              "triggerParameter": "connection"
            }
          ],
          "metadata": {
            "accountName": "my-account-name",
            "queueLength": "1",
            "queueName": "my-queue-name"
          },
          "name": "queue-job",
          "type": "azure-queue"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Nothing happens when new messages are put on the queue. KEDA keeps printing "Created 0 jobs" to the logs, so it seems that it is running.

What is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: does the whoe config looks like the one is the sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-resource-manager#event-driven-jobs

Comment: did you configure the connectionstrin secret etc ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that, and the connection string secret was defined. I ended up deploying a new container app job with the same config, and it worked... Not sure what happened here.

Comment: good to hear that it is working now